# How can I plug a prediction of X into BernoulliNB.predict_proba?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a Python script that, given an observed class (X) and some columns of binary (Y), predicts a class (Pred_X). It then predicts the probability of each class (Prob(1), etc). How could I get the probability of only the observed class (Prob(X)) please?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
BNB = BernoulliNB()

# Data
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'X' : [1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1],
                     'Y1': [1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1],
                     'Y2': [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
                     'Y3': [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]})

# Split the data
df_I = df_1 .loc[ : , ['Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3']]
S_O  = df_1['X']

# Bernoulli Naive Bayes Classifier
A_F = BNB.fit(df_I, S_O)

# Predict X
A_P = BNB.predict(df_I)
df_P = pd.DataFrame(A_P)
df_P.columns = ['Pred_X']

# Predict Probability
A_R = BNB.predict_proba(df_I)
df_R = pd.DataFrame(A_R)
df_R.columns = ['Prob_1', 'Prob_2']

# Join
df_1 = df_1.join(df_P)
df_1 = df_1.join(df_R)
```

Comment: The question is unclear. You have `Prob_1` and `Prob_2` as probabilities of classes. Whichever is highest in a single row will be the predicted class for that row. In `Pred_X` column, you have that predicted class. What else do you want?

Comment: To get the largest of Prob_1 and Prob_2 in one column please @VivekKumar

Comment: Or actually thinking again I would really like to have the probability of the original X value in a single column.

Comment: So my question should be: "How can I plug a prediction of X into BernoulliNB.predict_proba?"

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You will then not be able to tell if that probability is of class 1 or class 2 unless you look at the `Pred_X` column. If you want a single column only, then you should either keep `Prob_1` or `Prob_2` only. Other probability can be easily found out by subtracting from 1.

Comment: Ok but I would like it to work for more than 2 classes as well

Comment: In that case, only keeping the highest probability will not make any sense even more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182343/discussion-between-r-cox-and-vivek-kumar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @jezrael:

```
# Rename the columns after the classes of X
classes = df_1['X'].unique()
df_R.columns = [classes]

# Look up the predicted probability of X
df_1['Prob_X'] = df_R.lookup(df_R.index, df_1.X)
```

Comment: This approach estimates the probability of each class for each row and it then looks up the value for X. It would be less computation to only estimate the probability of X for each row.

Comment: This works on the dummy data. On the real data, I'm getting: "df_R.columns = [classes]" / "ValueError: Length mismatch"